# How to debug Rails errors in Gitlab CI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am new on Gitlab, so this is possibly a beginner question.

I just migrated my Rails repo to Gitlab - pretty basic, no tests yet. But it seems the CI pipeline seems to fail here:

```
$ rails db:migrate
rails aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant ApplicationPolicy
/builds/sapi/app/policies/request_update_policy.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/builds/sapi/config/application.rb:28:in `each'
/builds/sapi/config/application.rb:28:in `<class:Application>'
/builds/sapi/config/application.rb:20:in `<module:SDOTApi>'
/builds/sapi/config/application.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
```

Now the problem is that I can’t reproduce this in my local repo. So, I am not sure how best to debug this given that I didn’t think should be occurring in the first place (and certainly, not in this unused policy file compared to all other policy files).

So, a few questions:

1. How can I log in to the CI console to debug this?
2. Any tips or idea what might be going on?
3. How can I turn off CI if I need to (not per commit message, but in general for the project)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately [web terminals](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/environments.html#web-terminals) are only available when using a deployment service (e.g. Kubernetes)

However, if you have access to the runner, you can manually login via ssh and use the gitlab-runner binary to execute (i.e. using the `gitlab-runner exec` command) the failing job from the git repo it cloned.

In case you don't have access to the runner but you're using Docker-based jobs, you can always use locally the [GitLab Runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/) binary for your OS to run and debug your job:

```
cd <project-root>
/usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner exec docker <job-name>
```

After it fails, you can start back the container it spawned to run a terminal (using `docker exec`) and debug what went wrong inside it. You have a more complete explanation on this in https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#how-to-debug-a-job-locally

To disable the CI for the whole project, you can turn off the "Pipelines" switch at your project's General Settings:

[image: disable_gitlab_ci_project]

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I don't have a docker image and was using their default CI/CD environment. So I guess there isn't much I can do to debug :/

Comment: @geoboy oh, you don't need your own docker image. If you're using their shared runners, that means the config that's being set for you is probably docker running some of the ruby base images. See https://gitlab.com/ayufan/ruby-getting-started/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml for a GitLab's CI example ruby app.